# Best practice when deploying multi layered project in to production

Tags: asp.net-core, architecture

net core solution with different projects as below,

- API - Contains Controllers where the client side application are calling
- Application - Has the business logics
- Data - DbContext
- Domain - Has the classes for the tables in the Data project
- Infrastructure - Generate token

My question is when I go into production environment, Is it possible to have the APIs in a different server and Application, Data, Domain, Infrastructure in a different server? Is that the best practice?

Any help, ideas, suggestions are highly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the first question is that it is possible. One way to understand this is to recognize that the interface between a UI and an API is similar to the proposed interface between an API and a backend. In the same way that the UI is usually on a different server than the API, the API may be on a different server than associated business logic. As long as the interfaces between each component are understood and used within their scope there is no reason different segments of a production application cannot be on different servers. The principle behind this is commonly known as 'separation of concerns'.

1. UI - understands how to 'receive' data from the API and 'send' data to the user.
2. API - understands how to 'receive' data from the UI and 'send' data to business logic handling
3. Application - understands how to 'receive' data from the API and 'send' data to the data store.

The second part of this question is similar to the question between whether microservice or monolith architecture should be preferred. In a microservice architecture, each service should handle one operation well and other components should communicate with it through a clearly defined interface. This results in code and a deployment which is easier to follow and scale at the cost of the effort involved in standardizing and maintaining interfaces and issues associated with communicating over a network.

If there was one architecture which was the best in all aspects then everyone would use that and there would be no need for further evaluation. With that said,
in my opinion the benefits of partitioning services is proportional to the number of unique services there are. As such, splitting only into an API and backend server is not worthwhile. As the number of 'separated concerns' increase (ex: many backend components), the benefits start to become more worthwhile.

It may be worth further partitioning your backend into a number of distinct services. Ex: Application business logics may be partitioned into Type1, Type2, and Type3.